# Angular 4 (click) only fire once in dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript

ive the following problem:

After i logged out and in again in my angular-app the Logout-Button stops working.
The (click) event wont fire until i hard refreshed the site with F5.

navbar.component.html

```
//In Navbar
<mz-navbar-item-container [align]="'right'">
  <a *ngIf="auth" id="btn-dropdown-demo" class="waves-effect waves-light" href="#">Menu▾</a>
</mz-navbar-item-container>
[....]
//After Navbar
<mz-dropdown *ngIf="auth"
         [id]="'dropdown-demo'"
         [align]="'right'"
         [belowOrigin]="true"
         [constrainWidth]="false"
         [dropdownButtonId]="'btn-dropdown-demo'"
         [inDuration]="300"
         [outDuration]="300"
         [stopPropagation]="true">
  <mz-dropdown-item><a href="#!">Profile</a></mz-dropdown-item>
  <mz-dropdown-item><a href="#!">Settings</a></mz-dropdown-item>
  <mz-dropdown-divider></mz-dropdown-divider>
  <mz-dropdown-item><a (click)='goTo("logout")'>Logout</a></mz-dropdown-item>
</mz-dropdown>
```

navbar.component.ts

```
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private auth: boolean; //is true/false and will be refreshed if user do a login/logout
  private sharedSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService, private router: RoutingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedSub = this.sharedService.getLoggedIn().subscribe(isLoggedIn => {this.auth = isLoggedIn; });
    this.sharedService.refreshLogin();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sharedSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  private goTo(site: string) {
    this.router.navigateTo(site);
  }
}
```

On Logout, the user-token will be deleted and the app routes to /login (without reloading the navbar.component )
Do you have any ideas what could be my error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with ng2-materialize but putting the angular-click-directive inside an HTML a-tag seems to be wrong.

```
<mz-dropdown-item><a (click)='goTo("logout")'>Logout</a></mz-dropdown-item>
```

Maybe this is why the framework crashes in background and only a reset by F5 repairs this.

I'd try to implement a button-element instead. But this is just hipshooting:

```
<mz-dropdown-item><button mz-button (click)="goTo('logout')">Logout</button></mz-dropdown-item>
```